# Choose 6 teachers out of 30, order doesn't matter

Tags: combinatorics

A school director must randomly select 6 teachers to participate in a training session. There are 30 teachers at the school. In how many different ways can these teachers be selected, if the order of selection does not matter?

Answer (score 1):

If the order mattered it would be $30\cdot29\cdot28\cdot27\cdot26\cdot25$ since there would be $30$ option for the first to be picked, $29$ for the second to be piecked and so on...

However if order does not matter each unordered selection appears $6\cdot5\cdot4\cdot3\cdot2$ in the ordered selections.

So the answer you are looking for is $\frac{30\cdot29\cdot28\cdot27\cdot26\cdot25}{6\cdot5\cdot4\cdot3\cdot2}$

Using factorial notation this is $\frac{30!}{6!(30-6)!}$

using binomial coefficient notation this is $\binom{30}{6}$ or $30\text C6$

Answer (score 0):

This is just "30 choose 6." If you have a graphing calculator, under the Probability menu there should be something like nCr. But your textbook should contain the relevant formula--and explain the basis for it.

Answer (score 0):

you must read permutation and combination textbook or section first.
answer is  30C6=(30*29*28*27*26*25)/(6*5*4*3*2*1)=593775 
I don't think it can be explained here.